# Sorting an array of 1000 integers

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I'm having an issue sorting an array of 1000 integers with the following code. It worked fine with 10 integers but with 1000 it seems keep going I'm assuming it's some kind of memory leak.

I've never sorted before a small explanation of my errors would be helpful also.

Thank you

```
    class RandomNumbers
    {
    private:

        int intRandomNumbers;

    public:
        int getRandomNumbers();
        void setRandomNumbers(int intPRandomNumbers);
        RandomNumbers(void);
     };

-----------------------------------------------------------
     void printArray(const int intArray[], int intLength);
     int searchFull(const int intArray[], int intLength, int intSearchItem);
     void sortBubble(int intArray[], int intLength);
     int searchLinear(const int intArray[], int intLength, int intSearchItem);
     int searchBinary(const int intArray[], int intLength, int intSearchItem);

--------
     //Getters and setters for RandomNumber class.

     RandomNumbers::RandomNumbers()
     {
     setRandomNumbers(0);
     }

     void RandomNumbers::setRandomNumbers(int intPRandomNumbers)
     {
     intRandomNumbers = intPRandomNumbers;
     }

     int RandomNumbers::getRandomNumbers()
     {
     return intRandomNumbers;
     }

     void printArray(const int intArray[], int intLength) {
    for(int intIndex = 0; intIndex < intLength - 1; intIndex++) {
        cout << intArray[intIndex] << ", ";
    }
    cout << intArray[intLength - 1] << endl;
      }

        int searchFull(const int intArray[], int intLength, int intSearchItem) {
    int intLocation = -1;
    int intCounter = 1;
    for(int intIndex = 0; intIndex < intLength; intIndex++) {
        cerr << "searchFull: " << intCounter++ << endl;
        if(intArray[intIndex] == intSearchItem)
        {
            intLocation = intIndex;
        }
    }
    return intLocation;
        }

        void sortBubble(int intArray[], int intLength){
    int intTemp = 0;
    int intIteration = 0;
    int intIndex = 0;
    for(intIteration = 1; intIteration < intLength; intIteration++) {
        for(intIndex = 0; intIndex < intLength - intIteration; intIndex++) {
            if(intArray[intIndex] > intArray[intIndex + 1]) {
                intTemp = intArray[intIndex];
                intArray[intIndex] = intArray[intIndex + 1];
                intArray[intIndex + 1] = intTemp;
            }
            printArray(intArray,intLength);
            }
           }
           }

           int searchLinear(const int intArray[], int intLength, int intSearchItem) {
       int intLocation = -1;
       int intCounter = 1;
       for(int intIndex = 0; intIndex < intLength && intSearchItem >= intArray[intIndex];                 intIndex++)   intIndex++) 
   {
        cerr << "searchLinear: " << intCounter++ << endl;
        if(intArray[intIndex] == intSearchItem)
        {
            intLocation = intIndex;
        }
    }
    return intLocation;
}

int searchBinary(const int intArray[], int intLength, int intSearchItem) {
    int intFirstIndex = 0;
    int intLastIndex = intLength - 1;
    int intMiddle = 0;
    bool boolFound = false;

    while(intFirstIndex <= intLastIndex && !boolFound) {
        intMiddle = (intFirstIndex + intLastIndex) / 2;
        if(intArray[intMiddle] == intSearchItem) {
            boolFound = true;
        } else if(intArray[intMiddle] > intSearchItem) {
            intLastIndex = intMiddle - 1;
        } else {
            intFirstIndex = intMiddle + 1;
        }
        cerr << "searchBinary: " << intFirstIndex << ", " << intMiddle << ", " << intLastIndex << endl;
    }

    if(boolFound) {
        return intMiddle;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}


    int main() {

    srand (time(NULL));

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("RandomNumber.txt");

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
        {
            int RandomNumbers = rand() % 1000 + 1;
            myfile << RandomNumbers << "\n";
        }
    }

       myfile.close();

    int array_size = 1000;
    int * array = new int[array_size];
    int position = 0;

    ifstream fin("RandomNumber.txt");

    if(fin.is_open())
    {
        cout << "File opened!!! Loading array. ";

        while(!fin.eof() && position < array_size)
        {
            fin >> array[position];
            position++;
        }

        cout << "Displaying array..." << endl <<endl;

        for(int intIndex = 0; intIndex < array_size; intIndex++)
        {
            cout << array[intIndex] << endl;
        }
        fin.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout<< "File could not be opened." << endl;
    }



    cout << searchFull(array, array_size, 43) << endl;
    cout << searchLinear(array, array_size, 43) << endl; //Incorrect not sorted
    cout << searchFull(array, array_size, 5) << endl;
    cout << searchLinear(array, array_size, 5) << endl; //Incorrect not sorted

    sortBubble(array, array_size);

    cout << searchFull(array, array_size, 43) << endl;
    cout << searchLinear(array, array_size, 43) << endl;
    cout << searchBinary(array, array_size, 43) << endl;
    cout << searchFull(array, array_size, 5) << endl;
    cout << searchLinear(array, array_size, 5) << endl;
    cout << searchBinary(array, array_size, 5) << endl;

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
        };
```

Comment: Where are the other functions? What do they look like?

Comment: I just made an edit adding all of my code.

Comment: I extracted your sort routine without the `printArray` call and in a debug build it sorted 1000 random integers in 1ms, and 10000 random integers in 190ms.  I didn't examine the whole array, but printing the first and last 10 they appear to be in order.  Comment out the `printArray` call and try again.  If you still have a problem, use the debugger and when it seems like it's stuck, break and see where.

Comment: Commenting out printArray did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while(!fin.eof()` is a blunder. What happens after the last value has been read, but before `eof()` occurs?  (answer: You'll get the last entry copied twice). Fix it by going:

```
while ( position < array_size && fin >> array[position] )
    position++;
```

Also, you should be displaying and sorting with `position` as the counter, not `array_size`.

Maybe your `sortBubble` function has a bug, or maybe it is just taking a long time to run. What happens if you try with 100 numbers? Can you post the code for it?

Comment: The change in the while loop works well with only 100 integers but with 1000 integers it seems to be going non stop unless it's just taking that long.

Comment: Try increasing the number gradually from 100 to 1000 and observe how long it is taking to run each time